# FrameLayout does not display correct width

Tags: android, width, android-framelayout

I have a layout like below  ( to play media files ) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mediabar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="P">

        </Button>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/sbProgress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTimeleft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I use a class called CustomView which inherits from FrameLayout to contains the above layout.

```
public class CustomView extends FrameLayout
```

Then I will add the above layout to the CustomView on startup :

```
private void initItems(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = null;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shadow_layout,null,false);

    btnPlay = rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    seekBar = rowView.findViewById(R.id.sbProgress);
    tvTime = rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTimeleft);
    //scriptFrame = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.scriptframe);

    this.addView(rowView);
    setUpFont();
}
```

And finally, in my activity, I will create and add the above class to my view like this :

```
shadowingView = new CustomView(context);
shadowingView.setLayoutParams(
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

scrollView.addView(shadowingView);
```

But the result is not what I expected, the layout wasn't `MATCH_PARENT` (Play button's text is not displaying also) :

[image]

Please point me where I did wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks for the comment, but after changing the parent, the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

you miss the `android:weightSum` attribute in your `linearlayout`

```
<LinearLayout
        //put the weightSum here 
        android:id="@+id/mediabar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="P">

    </Button>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbProgress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTimeleft"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

here is the result :[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I think the weightsum isn't the root cause here

Comment: yes it is and also your seekbar and textview weight are not correct , please check my edit

Comment: i added the image for the result with the code i gave you

Answer (score 0):

your xml code is working fine here...... [image]

SHow me the code of

```
<FrameLayout
......
......
/>
```

There might be some error in it.....

Answer (score 0):

try using

shadowingView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys. Unfortunately none of the answers worked. But I have fixed the problem.

For some unknown reason, the `scrollview` is the problem, all I have to do is change from `FrameLayout` to `ScrollView`

```
public class CustomView extends ScrollView
```

And here :

```
shadowingView = new CustomView(context);
shadowingView.setLayoutParams(
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

// scrollView.addView(shadowingView);  REMOVE THIS LINE 
// topParent.addView(scrollView); AND THIS LINE 

topParent.addView(shadowingView)
```